# Run migrations on azure for dotnet core site deployed with GitHub

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a small website built with .Net core that includes a SQLite database and entity framework core.  I'm using VS Code and on a mac.

It is easy to manage the database locally - `dotnet ef database update` works great.  The problem is running migrations when deploying to Azure.

My repo is on GitHub, and I configured Azure to pull code from GitHub when I push to the master branch.  The deploy is working fine, but migrations aren't running on Azure.

I've seen some suggestions that I can use `yourDbContext.Database.Migrate()` in Startup.cs, however it appears that `.Migrate()` is no longer available.

I've tried downloading the deployment script from Azure and customizing it by adding `call :ExecuteCmd dotnet ef database update -e Production` to deploy.cmd, but that doesn't appear to be working.

I've tried using the PS shell I can access through the Kudu site to manually run migrations, but when trying to run `dotnet ef database update` the result is, `No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"`

There is a very similar question here ([EF Core (1.0.0) Migrations On Azure App Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39625615/ef-core-1-0-0-migrations-on-azure-app-services)), but that question did not get any answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can run `context.Database.Migrate()` when you initialize the database in your code. The migrations will run when you first launch your application

Comment: Thanks @matthijsb - I had seen this answer in a few places and it wasn't working for me.  I tried it again and got it to work.  The trick was I needed to add `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;` to the top of Startup.cs.  Without it I was still able to create the context and intellisense in VS Code found `.Database`. But it didn't find `.Migrate()` until the additional `using` was added.

Comment: Found an solution in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42624340/deploying-asp-net-core-web-app-sql-from-a-repository