# Deploying ASP.NET Core Web App + SQL from a repository

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm working on this tutorial, [Getting Started with ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework Core using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/), and I'd like to deploy it to Azure from a GitHub repository. Using "Web App + SQL" in Azure I can deploy it successfully once, but when I make a change to the database and redeploy I get the error, "Applying existing migrations may resolve this issue..."

So is there some way I can trigger a database update when the app is redeployed with a new migration present?

Just a note, I know there are ways to deploy and manage an app like this directly from Visual Studio, but I'd like to learn how to do it from a repository.

Note: I found this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40177798/run-migrations-on-azure-for-dotnet-core-site-deployed-with-github) and I tried adding `context.Database.Migrate()` to the Configure method of Startup.cs underneath `DbInitializer.Initialize(context);` and this didn't cause a problem when I ran it on my machine but when I deployed it I got "500 Internal Server Error: An error occurred while starting the application."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried adding context.Database.Migrate() to the Configure method of Startup.cs underneath DbInitializer.Initialize(context); and this didn't cause a problem when I ran it on my machine but when I deployed it I got "500 Internal Server Error: An error occurred while starting the application."

According to your description, I followed the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro) as you mentioned to test this issue. I added the `DbInitializer.cs` in this [section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro#add-code-to-initialize-the-database-with-test-data) and add `context.Database.Migrate()` under Configure method of `Startup.cs` as follows:

```
DbInitializer.Initialize(context);
context.Database.Migrate();
```

I added a new property named `IdNo` for Student class, then started the web application, I could encounter the following error:

[image]

**Note:** If the `Students` table has no any records, the `DbInitializer.cs` would add feed records, then I encounter the above error.

Here is the summary about `DatabaseFacade.EnsureCreated()` and `DatabaseFacade.Migrate()`:

**DatabaseFacade.EnsureCreated()**

> **Ensures that the database for the context exists. If it exists, no action is
>   taken**. If it does not exist then the database and all its schema are created.
>   If the database exists, then no effort is made to ensure it is compatible with
>   the model for this context.
>   **Note that this API does not use migrations to create the database**. In addition,the database that is created cannot be later updated using migrations. **If you are targeting a relational database and using migrations, you can use the DbContext.Database.Migrate()** method to ensure the database is created and all migrations are applied.

**DatabaseFacade.Migrate()**

> **Applies any pending migrations for the context to the database. Will create the database if it does not already exist.** Note that **this API is mutually exclusive with DbContext.Database.EnsureCreated()**.
>   EnsureCreated does not use migrations to create the database and therefore the
>   database that is created cannot be later updated using migrations.

Based on your scenario, you need to leverage migrations feature to update your database schema. As I known, EF Core does not support automaic migrations, you could follow this similar [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39526595/entityframework-core-automatic-migrations) and this git [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/6214). You could use `context.Database.Migrate()` instead of `context.Database.EnsureCreated()` in your `DbInitializer.cs` and manually add migration file via `add-migration`, and commit the created migration file to your GitHub repository.

[image]

**Note:** You need to take care of the seed data in `DbInitializer.cs`, in order to avoid inserting the same record.

Comment: Yes! I simply changed `context.Database.EnsureCreated()` to `context.Database.Migrate()` in `DbInitializer.cs` along with manually adding migration files and it's working beautifully. Thank you!